# Two different date format of Jquery date picker on same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get Jquery date picker on same id which changes its date format after an event. I tried below code snippet but unable to perform as expected.

**JS CODE**

```
function dateselect(){
    var type = jQuery('#uploadtype').val()
    if(type == "monthly"){ //if user select month as dropdown
        jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            }
        });
    }

    else{
            jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
                  beforeShowDay: displayValidDates,
                  maxDate: '-1w',
                  constrainInput: true,
                dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"
            });
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the format at runtime depending on a condition, it is best to initialize the datepicker with default and your function only change the formatting and other options you want.

Try....

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
              beforeShowDay: displayValidDates,
              maxDate: '-1w',
              constrainInput: true,
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"
         });

function dateselect(){
var type = jQuery('#uploadtype').val()

if(type == "monthly"){ //if user select month as dropdown

    $("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM yy" );
}

else{
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" )
}

}
```

You can check this example for more information:

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html